# How to address Qt5 controls using AutoIt script?

Tags: qt, qt5, autoit

I write AutoIt scripts to automate applications, but I don't know how to address Qt GUI controls (after obtaining the window handle through its title), like contained buttons, text boxes, etc.

Spy++ and other tools do not provide the right information (or am I wrong?). I can get, for example, using the Old button of his room, a child element of the window. This list of child elements comes up empty however.

Comment: Try getting it by id instead of title?

Comment: I try get list of child elements. But function return empty list. Please, give me example of get-by-id code)